# Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I don't undestand why:
The set of continuos functions from a metric space X→R, C(X), forms a vector space over R using the usual definitions of addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: This is much more basic than a reproducing kernel hilbert space. What do you think goes wrong?

Comment: I'm ignorant.Usually a vector space is made of tuples of coordinates. I can't understand how they relates to functions...

Comment: I see. In which case I would refer you to e.g. wikipedia for the definition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space In the section "Definition", you can see that there are 8 properties a vector space needs to satisfy. Can you verify those?

Comment: I dont' undestand how to treat a function as coordinates.

Comment: The answer is you don't. You only want to verify that as a set $V=C(X)$, equipped with an addition $+: V\times V\to  V$, and a scalar multiplication $\bullet : \mathbb R \times V \to V$, satisfies the 8 properties. No mention of coordinates anywhere

Comment: Can I ask what is the meaning of adding two functions?

Comment: You may, $f+g$ is defined to be the function $h\in C(X)$ given by $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$.

Comment: My apologies, I had written + wrong in the earlier comment. It is $V\times V\to V$, not $V \times V \to \mathbb R$ as I had previously typed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89634/discussion-between-calvin-khor-and-filippo-portera).